# Django with smtp.gmail.com with secured google apps account

Tags: django, django-forms, google-apps, contact-form, django-settings

Django websites were working 100% with contact form that sends email via google apps. Recently it stopped working that I need to turn on this feature:

```
Allowing less secure apps to access your account
```

Link:

```
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en
```

How to achieve to send emails via contact form using google apps but secured way. I do not want my google apps account to be less secure only because of this contact form. Is there a way to set an exception in google apps account for this website / IP or somehow? I would like to have it set proper way.

This setting worked previously till now when I had to turn on less secure apps feature on.

```
RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY = env("RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY", default='XXX')
RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY = env("XXX", default='RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY')
CONTACT_EMAIL_SUBJECT = 'CUSTOM SUBJECT'

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'EMAIL ADDRESS'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'EMAIL PASSWORD'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'EMAIL ADDRESS'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```